# Named routes and restful controllers issue

Tags: routes, laravel

I have the following code in routes.php :

`Route::controller('/', 'HomeController', array( 'getIndex' => 'home' ));`

Strangely, when I do `URL::route('home')`, it gives me `http://domain.com/index` and I expect `http://domain.com/`

This happens everywhere where I have a name for the `getIndex()` method. It just appends `/index`. Why does it happen? How to remove that?

Comment: I had the exact same question... looks like I'll be going back to manually routing as well. I can see pros and cons to both ways but would prefer not to use hacks to outsmart the RESTful controller in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You can't remove the `/index` in this case. It's a `Route::controller()` feature.

Here are two issues talking about that: [issue #1278](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1278) and [issue #2043](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/issues/2043).

> This was changed in order to allow for `action('Controller@getIndex', array('v1' => 'foo'))` to become `/signup/index/foo` instead of `/signup?v1=foo`. Look at the wildcards added to every route, they include `v1`...`v5`
>   – [*JoostK*](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1278#issuecomment-17782892)

A workaround is to add a route for it before `Route::controller()`:

```
Route::get('/', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@getIndex']);
```

---

But I'm not a fan of RESTful nor Resourceful controllers, so I don't use it anymore, I just write all my routes.

Take a look at this Phil Sturgeon's post [Beware the Route to Evil](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2013/07/beware-the-route-to-evil).

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid RESTful Controller for the home page. Try to separate the home page like the following:

```
Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@index'));
```

And for the rest of your routes, you can use RESTful Controller.

```
Route::controller('/', 'HomeController', array( 'getLogin' => 'Login'));
```

**Best practice:** Avoid RESTful Controller in your application.

Why?

http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2013/07/beware-the-route-to-evil

Comment: This merely promotes the idea that RESTful controllers are wrong, which is in no way an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like using restful controllers, even for homepages.  I think having all your simple, static pages in a restful controller named HomeController or something is a good practice.  I use it in all the stuff I do.  To get around the issue you're having, I just make the link something like `URL::to('/')`.  Keeping a clean looking `routes.php` makes finding the route to a specific controller much easier later.